# How to find the Voc for this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, norton

I've got the following:

[image]

And I'm unsure how to find the voltage at this node so that I can use Voltage Divider to find the Open Circuit voltage. What should my approach be to find this voltage?

Comment: Independence of sources: do calculation without the current source; same replacing power source by simple wire; add results

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. You are not allowed to post such questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct to use the principle of superposition.
Assuming that you need voltage between A and B and also for the node circled in red (I call it C).

**Part 1: only 5V voltage source**

The current source is made "passive", going to infinite impedance.

V_AB_1 = 800 / (2600 + 2400) * 5V = 0.8V

With no load connected between A and B, V_CB_1 may be calculated as:

V_CB_1 = (800 + 2600) / (2400 + 800 + 2600) * 5V = 3.4V

**Part 2: only 10mA current source**

The voltage source is made "passive", going to zero impedance.

V_CB_2: 10mA current goes into the parallel of the left and right branches; thus:

Z2 = 2400 // (2600 + 800) = 2400*(2600+800)/(2400+2600+800) = 1407 ohm

V_CB_2 = Z2 * 10 mA = 14.07 V

The current flowing in the right arm is given by V_CB_2 divided by the resistance of that arm:

I_right = V_CB_2 / (2600 + 800) = 4.1 mA

V_AB_2 = I_right * 800 ohm = 3.31 V

**Part 3: putting things together**

Superposition of the two scenarios:

V_AB = V_AB_1 + V_AB_2 = 0.8 + 3.31 = 4.11 V

V_CB = V_CB_1 + V_CB_2 = 3.4 + 14.07 = 17.47 V

Note. Sign of current and voltage are such that the voltages of Part 1 and 2 are summed correctly, taking into account the sign.

Comment: @Pixel Rain. Now, please, do your next homework by yourself!

Answer (score -1):

Simply apply the principle of **superposition**: replace your current source with an open circuit, and calculate the voltage across the 800Ohm resistor. Then, replace your voltage source with a short circuit, and again calculate the voltage across the 800Ohm resistor, remembering that currents at a node will always sum to zero (Kirchoff's Current Law). The solution will be the sum of the two.